# Database structure with OneToOne annotations

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm writing a webapp and can't figure out which one of the two following ways should I take.
Imagine 5 tables: A, B, C, D, and E. 
**Option 1:**
Use ids as foreign keys and then it looks like this:
tableA: **id**, field1, field2, ...
tableB: **tableA_id**, field1, field2, ...
tableC: **tableB_id**, field1, field2, ... etc...
**Option 2:**
Create new columns that will serve as foreign keys and then it looks like this:
tableA: **id**, field1, field2, ...
tableB: **id**, **tableA_id**, field1, field2, ...
tableC: **id**, **tableB_id**, field1, field2, ... etc...
I think option 1 might be a bit confusing when we call tableB id field which is infact named tableA_id but I might be wrong so I'll be glad if someone enlightens me a little. 
Also, if option 2 is the way to go, what is the point of joining tables on primary key?
**EDIT:** What I am trying to achieve is something like this:
Account
...Character
......Items
......Messages
......Other stuff

Comment: are you trying to model a tree?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm just trying to figure out which way is the proper way. In my case there is account table which holds exactly 1 character which holds for example items table, messages, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating new columns as foreign keys (option 2) simply because it's less confusing.
Thanks for your suggestion though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "Option 2", though you may need to be a bit more specific as to your goal here.  Might I suggest an Option 3:

```
 TableX: id, A_id, B_id, C_id, D_id, E_id
```

then:

```
Table_A: id, col1, col2
Table_B: id, colX, colY
Table_C: id, thing1
Table_D: id, more_col
Table_E: id, xxx
```

Then, it's just a simple join:

```
 SELECT A.col1, B.colX, C.thing1, D.more_col, E.xxx
    FROM TableX X
    LEFT JOIN Table_A as A on X.A_id = A.id
    LEFT JOIN Table_B as B on X.B_id = B.id
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: It's an interesting solution but in Spring data I don't do any SQLs manually, instead I just make a call to repository with appropriate function and hibernate does this for me so I'd have to call the TableX all the time. I also updated what I'm trying to achieve.